# Login Prompt for wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Good day/evening guys, so i have a wordpress website that i want to include a Pinterest Like login/register prompt logic but i can't seem to find the right plugin for that. let me again explain what i mean by that, when you are on a pinterest website and you scroll down trying to view more images, you get this popup that asks you to login or sign up, so how do i do this on a wordpress site with the help of a plugin or anything else, i am comfortable with php and javascript. i would like to do this whenever a user tries to access a certain link on the website. Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're just trying to have a popup / modal appear to prompt a user a to log in when they scroll down the page?

Have you tried any of these?:

https://themeisle.com/blog/scroll-triggered-pop-ups-on-wordpress/

https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-create-a-wordpress-login-popup-modal-step-by-step/

Comment: Thanks for the response,  i indeed tried that, what i am looking for exactly is when a user is not loged in then only then a popup is shown to ask them to login or signup.